# selenium webdriver BrokenPipeError (timeout issue)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I've boiled my code down to the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
b = webdriver.Firefox()
sleep(10)
b.get('http://www.google.com')
```

This causes a BrokenPipeError on the ***b.get*** call. Is this an error with my environment? Something I'm doing wrong, or a bug?

ENV:

- Fedora 27 (64bit)
- Firefox Quantum 59.0.2 (64bit)
- Python 3.6.5
- selenium 3.13.0 (via pip)
- geckodriver v0.21.0 from github

**Update:**
I upgraded my workstation and along with that moved to Fedora 28 with a brand new install of Firefox 61, Python 3.6.5, Selenium 3.13.0, and geckodriver 0.21.0 and I have the same problem with the provided script.

Comment: I think `geckodriver` works on FF 47+ and not below. Your FF is very old.

Comment: @demouser123 I forgot to include my firefox version. I've added it above. I using version 59.0.2

Comment: Also please update Selenium. Version `3.1.3` is very old.

Comment: it's Selenium version 3.13.0 (the latest according to https://pypi.org/project/selenium/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the path of the webdriver.exe file 
first specify path ='path of your webdriver.exe'

```
path ='path of your webdriver.exe'
and then b = webdriver.Firefox(path)
```

Comment: Not necessarily. If you have added the webdriver's location to your system/user path, you do not need to specify it when you invoke the browser.

Comment: It's in the in the path and opens. It's just that if there is a delay in commands being sent the pipe breaks. If commands are executed as soon as possible the pipe won't break. My original code loaded several pages before asking for input, if there was any delay in a response, the pipe would break. In testing, I boiled it down to the code I included in the question

Answer (score 0):

I use this method to fix this problem and I call it every time there is a risk for timeout. I hope there is a better solution, but this works for me right now.

```
def refresh(b):
    try: 
        b.refresh()
    except BrokenPipeError:
        pass
```